# Calling stored procedure inside another stored procedure in teradata

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

I am calling multiple stored procedures inside parent stored procedure however in need to make sure that if any on the SP fails it should not fail the whole stored procedure, instead it should moved to the next child below is the code for my stored procedure. Database is TERADATA.

​

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE DP_SI.LOAD_GEBAYA_SI_TABLE_PROCEDURE ()
BEGIN

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_TRANSACTIONS');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_TRANSACTIONSTATUS');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_REGIONS');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_PAYMENTSTATUS');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_REQUESTHISTORY');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_PRODUCTIONCOST');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_REQUESTS');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_REQUESTSTATUS');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_REQUESTSTYPES');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_TYPEPRICES');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_USERDETAILS');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_USERITEMS');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_ANAAMSUBTYPES');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_ANAAMTYPES');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_ATTACHMENTS');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_CITIES');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_PAYMENTS');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_PRICEREGIONS');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_PAYMENTTYPES');

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_GEBAYA_PROCEDURE_INTERNAL ('STG_GEBAYA_WORKERS');

 

END;
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a [condition handler](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Enterprise_IntelliFlex_VMware/SQL-Stored-Procedures-and-Embedded-SQL/Condition-Handling/Conditions-and-Condition-Handlers).

Comment: I tried this link but it is not working.

Comment: Works fine for me. But you can go to https://docs.teradata.com and search/ filter for _Condition Handlers_

Comment: it is working fine when i call only two procedures but not working fine when i add all of the stored procedures that i was to call. can you please have a look at the  script.
REPLACE PROCEDURE DP_SI.LOAD_GEBAYA_SI_TABLE_PROCEDURE_EXCEPTION ()
BEGIN
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_PROCEDURE ('STG_GEBAYA_TRANSACTIONSss');
Begin
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION

call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_PROCEDURE ('STG_GEBAYA_TRANSACTIONSTATUSss');
Begin
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
call  DP_SI.LOAD_SI_PROCEDURE ('STG_GEBAYA_REGIONS');
end;
end;
End;

Comment: The same condition handler will be in effect for the block in which it is defined; there is no reason here for you to nest multiple. Just `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ... ;` once after the BEGIN for the main block and before the first CALL. You can leave the body of the handler null or you could have a BEGIN/END block within the handler that takes some action like setting SQLSTATE to '00000'; An error transfers control to the handler. If the handler ends without explicitly transferring control, execution resumes at the next statement after the one generating the exception.